# How to make forms in dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I was trying to make an admissions portal bot and my requirement is to ask the user to enter basic information in a form and click on submit inside the bot itself. Any ideas on how to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of forms in Dialogflow, you would just ask the user for the information that you need. Actions on Google has '[Helpers](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers)' for commonly required user information that return the users response as structured data, but if you need something more specific you would have to parse the users response on your own (preferably via a [`developer entity`](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities#developer_entities)).